# Python - How to remove decimals without rounding up

Tags: python, import, decimal, rounding, currency

Im a little new into python, and i wanted to test it out, my idea was to make a script, that would see how much stuff you could buy for a certain amount of money.
The problem with this project though, is that i dont know remove the decimals, just like you like if you had 1,99 dollar and a soda costed 2 dollar, you technically wouldn't have enough money for it. Here is my script:

```
Banana = 1
Apple = 2
Cookie = 5

money = input("How much money have you got? ")
if int(money) >= 1:
    print("For ", money," dollars you can get ",int(money)/int(Banana),"bananas")
if int(money) >= 2:
    print("Or ", int(money)/int(Apple), "apples")
if int(money) >= 5:
    print("Or ", int(money)/int(Cookie)," cookies")
else:
    print("You don't have enough money for any other imported elements in the script")
```

Now, if i enter for example, 9 in this script, it will say i can get 1.8 cookies, how do i make it say i can get 1 cookies when entering fx 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you are using Python 3, because you are talking about getting the float result 1.8 when you are dividing two integers 9 and 5.

So in Python 3, there is an **integer division operator** `//` you can use:

```
>>> 9 // 5
1
```

vs

```
>>> 9 / 5
1.8
```

As for Python 2, the `/` operator by default does the integer division (when both operands are ints), unless you use `from __future__ import division` to make it behave like Python 3.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't expect it to be that easy :D

Comment: It's worth noting that the `//` operator exists in (non-ancient versions of) Python 2, too, and it's the preferred way to spell integer division regardless of which version of Python you're using. Don't use `/` when integer division is intended, even in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use **math.floor**

Updated code:

```
import math
Banana = 1
Apple = 2
Cookie = 5

money = input("How much money have you got? ")
if int(money) >= 1:
    print("For ", money," dollars you can get ",math.floor(int(money)/int(Banana)),"bananas")
if int(money) >= 2:
    print("Or ", math.floor(int(money)/int(Apple)), "apples")
if int(money) >= 5:
    print("Or ", math.floor(int(money)/int(Cookie))," cookies")
else:
    print("You don't have enough money for any other imported elements in the script")
```